# what is difference between model->name and model() in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I want to know the difference between laravel eloquent `conisgnment->runsheet->name` and `$consignment->runsheet()->name`

i notice that there is performance difference but why? also I notice that when I try to get relationship property like `$consignment->runsheet->name` it work fine but `$consignment->runsheet()->name` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one

```
$consignment->runsheet
```

retrieve a collection (so it's already made a query to DB)

while the second

```
$consignment->runsheet()
```

is a query builder (hasn't made a database query) you can chain it like any query builder instance

so if you want to get a property from the second one you can do it like:

```
$consignment->runsheet()->first()->name;
```

OR

```
$consignment->runsheet()->value('name');
```